# How to get all tweets after a DateTime with Twitter API and Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I currently want to look for a keyword and return all mentions of that word. I only want everything within the last 15 minutes though. I currently only know how to send a date and not DateTime. My code is as follows

```
def search_hash(api, since_id):
    logger.info("Retrieving tweets")
    search_words = "#keyword"
    date_since = "2021-04-28 13:48:01"
    new_since_id = since_id
    tweetss = tw.Cursor(api.search,
        q=search_words,
        result_type='latest',
        lang="en",
        count = 100,
        since=date_since,
        since_id=since_id).items()
    count = 0
    for tweet in tweetss:
        count = count + 1
        print(tweet.text)
        print(tweet.created_at)
        new_since_id = max(tweet.id, new_since_id)
    print(count)
    return new_since_id
```

I tried using date_since to be a datetime, but I do not think it is working correctly as it is returning times before my filter. Is their anyway to do a datetime?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by getting the ID of the latest tweet then using that id as the last id that should be checked and having the script run every 15 minutes while updating the last_id each time